# How to implement Vlookup formula drag down in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Why was the range (Rg) not called in vlookup function of my vba code below,  is there any correction needed to make it work right?

```
Sub Vlkuprangcall()
  Dim strColum As String
  Dim Rg As Range
  Set Rg = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F4:H9")

  With ActiveSheet
   a = ActiveCell.Column
   lastrow = 9
   strColumn = Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")(1)

   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-2],Rg,3,0)"
   ActiveCell.AutoFill Destination:=Range(ActiveCell, Range(strColumn & lastrow))

End Sub
```

Comment: You insert `Rg` in formula as text, not as a variable.

Comment: Use Named range is more suitable here. Say you named `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F4:H9")` as **LookUpTable**, then change to `.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-2],LookUpTable,3,0)"`. Also why is it not TURE/FALSE at last param of vlookup?

Comment: @PatricK It is `false` at the end ;)

Comment: @PatricK is the code is correct with i have set - Set Rg = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("F4:H9")
 ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="MyRange", RefersTo:=Rg

Comment: `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-2],Rg,3,0)"` -> `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-2],"&Rg.Address&",3,0)"`

Comment: @PatricK Thank u for your prompt reply... as per your advise i tried with named range but it didn't work -ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-2],MyRange,3,False)"

Comment: @HanSoalone  - i tried this code also saying syntax error :ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-2],"&Rg.Address&",3,0)"

Comment: Oh right, forgot RC doesn't accept A1 format, convert `"=vlookup(RC[-2]," & Rg.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",3,0)"`

Comment: @HanSoalone it is working perfectly .. thank u very much.. its really helpful for me and thank u all for giving the suggestion.

Comment: @HanSoalone - Hi the same concept of range allocation (Rg) not working with one workbook to another workbook - example  i set the range of workbook 2 (Misfile2)of the active sheet range (rngAdData), when i call the range (rngAdData) using vlookup in workbook 1 its not working- the code is : ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-2]," & rngAdData.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",15,False)"

Comment: Workbook to workbook cases you prolly need to pass the workbook reference seperately. Rg.Address if I remember correctly only passes the Sheet and cell reference, so you could probably do something with Rg.Parent.Parent.Name added to the string part. Can't test it atm, not at computer but it should work.

Comment: @HanSoalone i have the set the  code is : ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-15]," & Rg.Parent.Parent.Name & "!" & Rg.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) & ",6,False)" This formula working, it calling on the first sheet of wb 2, but thing is have set the range in third sheet of wb2 code is :Set Rg = wb2.Sheets(3).Range("A3:Z10000").. why  i am setting the range in third sheet because i want the range form specific sheet of the wb2-  please assist

Comment: With the same principle `Rg.Parent.Name` (?) should give you the name of the sheet and you can add it to the string.. I bet there is better way to do it but that's one option.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why in your setup isn't working for Naming that Range and use it to set FormulaR1C1. Did a mock up and below code works.

Consider this in Sheet1:
[image: MyRange on Sheet1]

And this in Sheet2:
[image: SampleDataSheet2]

Running the Sub yields:
[image: Result]

---

Code:

```
Sub VlkupRangCall()
    Dim strColumn As String, lastrow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastrow = 9
        strColumn = Split(ActiveCell.Address, "$")(1)

        .Range(ActiveCell, Range(strColumn & lastrow)).FormulaR1C1 = "=vlookup(RC[-2],MyRange,3,FALSE)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Things you can improve:

- Use a Table instead of fixed Range
- Rename this Table to something more meaningful say "MyRange" (just to match the code above)
- Avoid fixing the lastrow
- Use module level `Private Const` for these FormulaR1C1 if you have a lot of them to auto fill formula